# Received invalid pass data while updating Apple Wallet Pass

Tags: php, passbook, wallet

I have implemented all 5 endpoints in PHP and all seems working fine. But when I provide updated pass in response to web service **Getting the Latest Version of a Pass(*GET request to webServiceURL/version/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber*)** the pass is not updated and in error log I am receiving following error.

```
{"logs":["[2017-05-24 22:37:50 +0530] Get pass task (pass type pass.com.xxxx.xxxx, serial number 285527, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://www.xxxx.com/xx/xx/public/pass_api) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.)"]}
```

Also I am not sure what to pass in response to **Getting the Latest Version of a Pass** web service. Whether I should pass updated `pass.json` or raw file of `pass.pkpass` or downloadable format of `pass.pkpass`, because in Apple PassKit Web Service Reference guide its written like ***If request is authorized, returns HTTP status 200 with a payload of the pass data.*** So I am not sure what to pass as payload.

All my endpoints and entire code are in PHP.

Comment: Sounds like some error in the .pkpass bundle or signature.  Can you post a like to an updated pass?  Could also possibly be that you are not sending the correct headers with the updated .pkpass bundle.

Comment: @PassKit, yes you are right, i was passing wrong header and when i changed the header my pass got updated. Now i have one another question, is it possible that i can change a thumbnail image from my wallet and then don't allow to change in future ?

Comment: Hi - were you able to find out if you can send it as a donwloadable format? Also I'm having the same issue as you, what did you change in the header? Is it possible to see any code to refer to ?

Comment: You should answer your question with appropriate details if you solved the problem.

Comment: Hi, can you please add which headers were missing or incorrect? I'm having the same problem. Thanks