# Wallet Pass Update - The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid

Tags: php, passbook, wallet

I have implemented passbooks and updating. I'm using the `eo/passbook-bundle` and have created below JSON when packaging the passbook without errors, but when, in the update process, the server calls the `webServiceURL/version/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber` api, and the device downloads exactly the same JSON (but not packaged, just this json), it fails.

I've read in a comment on [Received invalid pass data while updating Apple Wallet Pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165482/received-invalid-pass-data-while-updating-apple-wallet-pass) that it may have something to do with correct headers, but there's no description whatsoever in the docs on any specific headers to return in the response  (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html)

I'm using symfony to return the response with the encoded json like this:

```
$json = PassFactory::serialize($storecard);
return new Response($json, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
```

I've also tried it without the Content-Type header.

In the log I can see: `Get pass task (pass type pass.com.spinpos.latest.customercard, serial number 5, if-modified-since (null); with web service url https://my.domain.com/api/loy/wallet/) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.)`

The JSON response is this:

```
{
   "storeCard":{
      "headerFields":[
         {
            "key":"prepaid",
            "value":"0,00",
            "label":"PREPAID"
         }
      ],
      "secondaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"username",
            "value":"Some Name",
            "label":"GEBRUIKERSNAAM"
         },
         {
            "key":"lastvisit",
            "value":"niet bekend",
            "label":"LAATSTE BEZOEK"
         }
      ],
      "auxiliaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"qrcode",
            "value":"2690310109104",
            "label":"QR CODE"
         },
         {
            "key":"points",
            "value":20,
            "label":"LOYALTY PUNTEN"
         }
      ],
      "backFields":[
         {
            "key":"website",
            "value":"http://www.somesite.com",
            "label":"WEBSITE"
         },
         {
            "key":"phone_number",
            "value":"05311223344",
            "label":"TELEFOONNUMMER"
         },
         {
            "key":"terms_of_service",
            "value":"Dit zijn test algemene voorwaarden!",
            "label":"ALGEMENE VOORWAARDEN"
         }
      ]
   },
   "serialNumber":"5",
   "description":"Your Customer card",
   "formatVersion":1,
   "locations":[
      {
         "latitude":51.62,
         "longitude":5.55,
         "relevantText":"Some Loc 2"
      },
      {
         "latitude":51.7737967,
         "longitude":5.5513203,
         "relevantText":"Some loc 1"
      },
      {
         "latitude":52.2648569,
         "longitude":6.8018085,
         "relevantText":"Testdfdr"
      }
   ],
   "barcode":{
      "format":"PKBarcodeFormatQR",
      "message":"2690310109104",
      "messageEncoding":"iso-8859-1"
   },
   "barcodes":[
      {
         "format":"PKBarcodeFormatQR",
         "message":"2690310109104",
         "messageEncoding":"iso-8859-1"
      }
   ],
   "backgroundColor":"rgb(255,108,108)",
   "foregroundColor":"rgb(46,14,170)",
   "labelColor":"rgb(110,255,75)",
   "authenticationToken":"048cfd30e4baf1c3250f0c8c7500f998aee2da49",
   "webServiceURL":"https://my.domain.com/api/loy/wallet/"
}
```

Anyone any idea what's wrong with the JSON or the headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send an entire new, signed .pkpass bundle with a header `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`

Comment: Thanks :) That did it. Wish it was in the documentation ;)

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsood.  See the comment on this closed question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153378/ios-cant-open-pkpass-file-from-url